# Regex for Password: "Atleast 1 letter, 1 number, 1 special character and SHOULD NOT start with a special character"

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc

I need a regular expression for a password field.

The requirement is:

1. The password Must be 8 to 20 characters in length
2. Must contain at least **one letter** and **one number** and a special character from **`!@#$%^&*()_+`**.
3. **Should not start with a special character**

I have tried

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])[A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+]{8,20}
```

It works but how do you restrict special characters from beginning the password? Also if you have a more efficient regex than the one mentioned above please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't do that with a regex (don't think it's even possible). I would search throug the string char by char and have my counters.

Comment: You shouldn't do this - this is bad security practice. https://xkcd.com/936/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its simple, just add one more character class at the begining

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+]{7,19}$
```

- `[A-Za-z\d]` Ensures that the first character is an alphabet or digit.
- `[A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+]{7,19}` will match minimum 7 maximum 19 character. This is required as he presceding character class would consume a single character making the total number of characters in the string as minimum 8 and maximum 20.
- `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the string. Ensures that there is nothing following our ***valid password***

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iY7iH5/1)

```js
var pattern = new RegExp(/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+]{7,19}$/);

console.log(pattern.test("!@#123asdf!@#"));

console.log(pattern.test("123asdf!@#"));

console.log(pattern.test("12as#"));
```

Comment: @adiga I saw your edit. Its ok to replace with `\w` in look aheads But it may give you problems in first character class `[A-Za-z\d]` because `\w` => `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Note the `_` which is a special character, which may give you troubles if the use enters `_asdf234$%`. I think this cannot be treated as a valid. Hope it fine for you :)

Comment: Okay, my bad. Thought \w was for `A-Za-z`. Thank you.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R: how to make it generic like n numbers of special characters or n number of uppercase characters?