# Regular expression to validate a string for at least n number of Upper case, Lower case , number and special characters in a given string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a requirement to add ability to provide **minimum characters** (range 0 - 9) for each type (**Upper case, Lower case , number and special**) characters in password.

[image]

I found so many solutions which gives solution for at-least 1 special/uppercase/lowercase/number ([Regex for Password: "Atleast 1 letter, 1 number, 1 special character and SHOULD NOT start with a special character"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938415/regex-for-password-atleast-1-letter-1-number-1-special-character-and-should)) but there is no generic solution which can satisfy my requirement.

I tried below for at least n special characters in my string but it's not working.

```
function CheckSpecialChars(n, NewPassword){
  var PasswordPattern ="^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+]{n})[A-Za-z\\d!@#$%^&*()_+]{8,20}$";
  var NewPassword = $('#txt').val();
  var PasswordRegEx = new RegExp(PasswordPattern, 'g');
  if (!PasswordRegEx.test(NewPassword)) {
    $('.er').html('not matched');
    return false;
  }else{
    $('.er').html('matched');
    return false;
  }
}

// if minimum 2 special characters are mandatory
Valid String: sad@j234KSS&ff // has more than 2 special chars
Invalid String: sdf#kj034950 // has less than 2 special chars
```

Comment: Well, you should double backslashes in a constructor notation, and you should not use `"g"` flag with a regex that is used in `RegExp.test()` method. Try `var PasswordRegEx =/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+]{n})[A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+]{8,20}/;`

Comment: "double backslashes in a constructor notation" means?

Comment: `new RegExp(Pattern, flags)` - that's constructor notation. You'll need to escape backslashes with another backslash, hence double backslash.

Comment: You initialize a RegExp with a string. Thus, all backslashes inside are used as escape symbols. A regex engine needs a literal ``\`` before `d` to actually match a digit. Just try alerting your `PasswordPattern` and you will understand what I mean.

Comment: It isn't complicated `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` for at least one letter, `(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})` for two and so one.

Comment: Ah, there should also be `$` at the end. And yes, you need a RegExp constructor since you add the `n` as a variable.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: that was a typing mistake, i added now.'

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Itried (?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2}) but it didn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because you did something wrong. Note that it's only an example for two letters or more.

Comment: Ok, anyways thank you all for your help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to construct a regular expression using the constructor since **n** is variable. Here is an example:

Constructed regex with **n = 2**:

```js
var n = 2;
var constructedRegEx = "^(?=(?:.*[0-9]){" + n + ",})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){" + n + ",})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){" + n + ",})(?=(?:.*[[!@#$%^&*()_+]){" + n + ",}).+$";

var PasswordRegEx = new RegExp(constructedRegEx, 'm');

console.log(PasswordRegEx.test('@Al1#a2B'));
console.log(PasswordRegEx.test('@Al1#a2'));
```

**Example of a constructed regex:**

```
^(?=(?:.*[0-9]){2,})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2,})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2,})(?=(?:.*[!@#$%^&*]){2,}).+$
```

**Railroad Diagram:**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Description:**

```
    NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (at least 2
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){2,}                    end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (at least 2
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){2,}                    end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (at least 2
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){2,}                    end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (at least 2
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [!@#0^&*]                any character of: '!', '@', '#', '0',
                               '^', '&', '*'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){2,}                    end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gA2xA6/2)**

Comment: @JitendraPancholi You're welcome. I was waiting for you post up your question again, so I had a head start. :)